# How to remove outline of circle marker when using pyplot.plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm producing a scatter plot using pyplot.plot (instead of scatter - I'm having difficulties with the colormap)

I am plotting using the 'o' marker to get a circle, but the circle always has a black outline.

How do I remove the outline, or adjust its colour?

Comment: The API documentation is your friend: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/markers_api.html

Comment: That is useful for doing the reverse - I can easily have an outline that is not filled. Alternatively I can change the fill colour of a filled circle. It is not obvious to me from that page (which is where I was before I came here) how to change the outline colour.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To remove the outline of a marker, and adjust its color, use **`markeredgewidth`** (aka **`mew`**), and **`markeredgecolor`** (aka **`mec`**) respectively.

Using [this as a guide](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,
         y,
         color='blue',
         marker='o',
         fillstyle='full',
         markeredgecolor='red',
         markeredgewidth=0.0)
```

This produces:
[image: plot result]

As you notice, **even though the marker edge color is set, because the width of it is set to zero it doesn't show up.**

Comment: Just what I needed! supplementary fyi to set color, one has to use:  `color='blue',`  not `m̶a̶r̶k̶e̶r̶c̶o̶l̶o̶r̶=̶'̶b̶l̶u̶e̶'̶ `

Comment: @uhoh: Agreed - you can do that to set the color of the marker. My example didn't manually set that parameter as I was illustrating that despite being set, the `markeredgecolor` doesn't show up once the `markeredgewidth` is set to 0 (since those parameters work independently of `color`).

Comment: yep :) I just put it there for the next person like me who lands here.

Comment: Add `linewidth=0` if you want a true "scatter" plot without the line.

Comment: @Selah: why not use `plt.scatter` then?

Comment: `fillstyle` doesn't seem to be required because `markeredgewidth=0` is sufficient

Comment: @MD004 - Thank you - yes, that's correct. I left that there to illustrate that even though that option is set, it has no effect due to the marker edge width being set to 0

Answer (score 6):

From the [`pyplot` API docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html):

> markeredgecolor or mec    any matplotlib color

Example:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x = np.linspace(0,1,11)

In [4]: y = x * x

In [5]: plt.plot(x,y,'o',color="red", ms=15, mec="red")
Out[5]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x34e1cd0>]

In [6]: plt.show()
```

Yields:
[image: Figure]

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I am making a scatter plot with transparency (`alpha=0.25`).  If you don't explicitly remove the outline using `mew=0`, it comes in at a different transparency than the interior. Full function: `plt.plot(x,y,'o', color="red", alpha=0.1, ms=7, mec="red", mew=0)
`

Answer (score 2):

This is outlined in `matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter` documentation found at https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html

It specifies that line edge colors for scatter plot markers can be set with

```
 edgecolors : color or sequence of color, optional, default: ‘face’
 The edge color of the marker. Possible values:

 - ‘face’: The edge color will always be the same as the face color.
 - ‘none’: No patch boundary will be drawn.
 - A matplotib color.

 For non-filled markers, the edgecolors kwarg is ignored and forced to ‘face’ internally.
```

The width of the line edges can be specified with

```
`linewidths` : scalar or array_like, optional, default: None

The linewidth of the marker edges.

Note: The default edgecolors is ‘face’.
```

> You may want to change this as well. If None, defaults to rcParams lines.linewidth.