# How to remove outline of marker/change marker style when using plot.scatter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

It is easy to remove the outline of a marker in a with pure matplotlib plot ([SO link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403179/how-to-remove-outline-of-circle-marker-when-using-pyplot-plot-in-matplotlib) ) using `markeredgewidth=0.0`. It is equally easy to change marker style following [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html).

But clearly the same options do not apply to a a pandas plot.scatter object, and

```
df.plot.scatter(x='Supply',y='Demand', alpha=0.2, figsize=(6,6), s=100)
```

returns those annoying outlines around the markers. [image]

Besides, the plot might look neater with a different marker (hex, else). What is the way to pass pandas these options? Clearly I can simply redo the whole plot using matplotlib, but wonder if there is a quicker way.

Comment: how do you have a marker outline on a scatter plot? please add image of plot

Comment: Thanks Rachel, now added

Comment: the markers seem to be of uniform color, it's just that because some of them are in clusters that the difference in color seems apparent. You can specify different colors for supply and demand, e.g. green and red. Use the 'color' attribute

Comment: The outline is there, it's just a bit darker than the marker color itself. It is probably more visible if you zoom in

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html#visualization-scatter (see fig c), the green and darkblue one

Comment: Same thing as with my previous color. To be more precise, the outline only becomes visible when you add transparency through the alpha argument. However, I would like the transparency without the outline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As docs for [pandas.DataFrame.scatter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) say, we can pass optional keyword arguments to [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot) which in turn will pass some of them to a corresponding matplotlib plotting method, [matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) in your case.

So, for example, to eliminate the edges from the markers, and to change them to hexagons, you can write:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='Supply', 
                y='Demand', 
                alpha=0.2, 
                figsize=(6,6), 
                s=100, 
                linewidths=0.0,
                marker='h')
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem in the question. Unfortunately my hexagons overlap, so it's not exactly the hex plot I was expecting - i.e. non-overlapping hexagons. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: @famargar Take a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#hexagonal-bin-plot). I never used it myself though.

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted. But for some reason I am not getting tick labels on the x axis - it probably has to do with the fact that it’s a log-log plot. Well I guess that’s a different question...