# Show edges and faces of markers in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, legend

I have the attached plot, and I like the symbols as plotted with

```
ax.errorbar('mjd', 'aperMag3Ab', label='',        fmt='o',  color='k', ms=ms*1.4)
ax.errorbar('mjd', 'aperMag3Ab', label='WFCAM Y', fmt='o',  color='y', ms=ms)
```

basically repeated eight times in total. The legend I currently get with:

```
plt.legend(loc="upper left", ncol=2, fontsize=labelsize/1.4, frameon=True)
```

How do I get the outer black cirlces (for the WFCAM labels) and the inner black hexagons (for the VIRCAM labels) in the legend too?
[image]

Comment: I hope you checked this page already: https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403179/how-to-remove-outline-of-circle-marker-when-using-pyplot-plot-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to your data but if you explicitly set the `fmt`, `markeredgewidth` and `markeredgecolor` in the plot, it should show up in the legend as well.

As a minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.errorbar([0], [0], yerr = [0.25], label='WFCAM Y', fmt='o', markeredgecolor ='black', markeredgewidth = 1,  color='y', ms=10)
ax.errorbar([0], [1], yerr = [0.25], label='WFCAM Y', fmt='p', markeredgecolor ='black', markeredgewidth = 1,  color='r', ms=10)
plt.legend()
```

[image]